# Using viewpager with specific fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am creating an app that is using a viewpager to slide between 4 specific fragments.

All the examples of viewpager I have read so far, create new fragments each time the getPosition method of FragmentPagerAdapter is called. So it's something like:

```
return FragmentA.newInstance();
```

What I have done is the following:

In the main activity

```
public static final int FRAGMENTS = 4;
public static final String FRAGMENT_LIST ="LIST";
public static final String FRAGMENT_SETTINGS = "SETTINGS";
public static final String FRAGMENT_MAP = "MAP";
public static final String FRAGMENT_TICKET = "TICKET";

MainAdapter _adapter;
ViewPager _pager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(new FragmentMap(), FRAGMENT_MAP)
                .add(new FragmentList(), FRAGMENT_LIST)
                .add(new FragmentTicket(), FRAGMENT_TICKET)
                .add(new FragmentSettings(), FRAGMENT_SETTINGS)
                .commit();
    }

    _adapter = new MainAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    _pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    _pager.setAdapter(_adapter);
}
```

and in the adapter:

```
public class MainAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

FragmentManager _manager;

public MainAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    _manager = fm;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return _manager.getFragments().get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ActivityMain.FRAGMENTS;
}
}
```

This raises an exception because the adapter is trying to change the tag of each fragment in getItem

My questions are:

a) Is it incorrect to always use the same fragment every time? I have seen no example that uses the above method or a similar one, they always create a new instance in the getItem method

b) If I wish for fragments to have some persistence, then does that mean that I should store the data that should be held by each fragment in static variables and always create new instances that use those variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) You must create a new instance in the `getItem()` method, this method is not called every time you switch fragment from your viewpager.

I recommend you to use your adapter like

```
public class MainAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public MainAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            case 0 :
                return new FragmentMap();
            case 1 :
                return new FragmentList();
            case 2 :
                return new FragmentTicket();
            case 3 :
                return new FragmentSettings();
            default :
                return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ActivityMain.FRAGMENTS;
}
}
```

b) Fragments in FragmentPagerAdapter are persistents, and they will be recreate only if you switch several fragment in your ViewPager. You can set the refresh limit by `_pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` for exemple if you never want to recreate your fragments in your case.

For more information : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Comment: I have tried that, the problem is, when I use FragmentPagerAdapter I get an error saying that the view already has a parent, yet it works with FragmentStatePagerAdapter but then my problem is that as soon as I navigate out of the specific fragment it gets removed, so I can't use it by saying something like getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);

which I need because in the future, each fargment will communicate with the parent activity and send a message to it, which the activity will be using to update the other fragments

Comment: doh sorry, I didn't notice your setOffScreenPageLimit comment, I will try that, thanks

Comment: I also recomend you to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: Just to make it clear to whoever reads this, this wasn't the exact solution I wanted, but it was the one that helped me the most in reaching the solution I wanted.
What I did was: 

a) set the viewpager with the setOffScreeenPageLimit(0), that way it seems to remove the fragments other than the current one (or at least it stops throwing exceptions that the fragment already has a parent)
b) pass a List<Fragment> arguement to the adapter along with the fragment manager, and have the getItem method return the item from the list

this way I can have references to all the fragments used

Answer (score 0):

a) I think it's perfectly ok. They always create ne instance because it is easier and in many cases (like image gallery) it is better.

b) Static variables get lost if you send the app to backround and then return to it. Shared prefferences or bundle should do the work.

Comment: so if I create a constructor along the lines of :

    public MainAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments)

and then use getItem() to return a specific item from the list , it shouldn't be a problem?

when you say saving the variables to a bundle, would it be incorrect if I save the list of fragments to the bundle and then extract them from in in OnCreate?

Answer (score 0):

You should use FragmentStatePagerAdapter. If you fragmentstatepager adapter, you can remove or add fragment dynamically.